# Retrieve data with HttpUrlConnection even with bad http codes 403. 404, etc

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I have the following method that works fine, but it throws an exception when the server returns 403 code which results in the method to never return the server response.

```
public String ping(String lat, String lon)
{
    StringBuffer response = null;
    try
    {
        String url = "https://api.mysite.com";
        URL urlObj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = null;
        if (useProxy)
        {
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection(proxy);
        }
        else
        {
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
        }

        // add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Host", urlObj.getHost());
        con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        // con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

        String urlParameters = "{\"lat\":" + lat + ",\"lon\":" + lon + "}";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        // System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        // System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        // System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // print result
        // System.out.println(response.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response.toString();
}
```

How can I make this return the server response no matter what the server returns and even if the server responds with 403 code (or any other response code)?

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for if I got your question right. You can check the response code using the `con.getResponseCode();` and if it a success code ` HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK` you can use `con.getInputStream()` to read the data or else you can use `con.getErrorStream()` to read the error message.

Answer (score 2):

You only need to add an `if` block to make the code more robust like below:

```
public String ping(String lat, String lon)
{
    StringBuffer response = null;
    try
    {
        String url = "https://api.mysite.com";
        URL urlObj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = null;
        if (useProxy)
        {
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection(proxy);
        }
        else
        {
            con = (HttpsURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
        }

        // add reuqest header
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        con.setRequestProperty("Host", urlObj.getHost());
        con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        // con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");

        String urlParameters = "{\"lat\":" + lat + ",\"lon\":" + lon + "}";

        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            response = readResponse(con.getInputStream());

        } else {
           response = readResponse(con.getErrorStream());
        }      

        // print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response.toString();
}

private StringBuffer readResponse(InputStream in) {
   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

    return response;

}
```

HTH.